# Are the call-stacks from a RecordedFile in JFR complete?

Tags: java, jvm, method-call, jfr

For the duration of a recording using Java Flight Recorder, will all the methods that are called within that duration be listed in a RecordedFile?

Given that:

- I am not recording a subset of events.
- I have not created any custom events.
- I am using AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.10

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

First, JFR is a *sampling* profiler. It does not record *all* method transitions; it takes periodic samples instead. I.e. once in the specified time interval, it looks at the call stacks of the threads running at the moment.

Second, JFR tends to miss many samples when it [fails to traverse](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8252417) a valid Java stack. I demonstrated this effect in [my presentation](https://youtu.be/H6glyrKQlg8?list=PLNCLTEx3B8h4Yo_WvKWdLvI9mj1XpTKBr&t=545): JFR caught just one meaningless application stack trace out of 10 seconds of execution.

You can choose how many samples JFR collects by tuning the sampling `period` setting. The smaller is period - the more stack samples JFR collects. However, the smallest possible period is just 1 ms. Furthermore, the sampling frequency does not scale well with the number of running threads. There is just one thread that collects all `ExecutionSample` events, no matter how many cores your server has.

Comment: That happens because those profile only at safepoints, right? I also assume async-profiler is immune to this?

Comment: I marked your reply as the answer. Very detailed and extremely useful! I've been watching the videos your linked to. In one of the videos you mentioned someone at Jetbrains working on something similar for Windows. Do you have any update on this? Or possible something I could read/watch?

Comment: @Eugene JFR does not rely on safepoints, but [JVM bugs](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178287) prevent it from getting stack traces at certain points. Async-profiler has workarounds for these bugs.

Comment: @Byebye As far as I know, they have a working prototype of async-profiler on Windows, and expect it to ship in one of the future versions of IDEA. No obligations though.